# SQL Insert not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When the event `Button` is pressed *nothing* updates in the SQL Table and *no errors* display.

```
protected void SubmitBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Matt\Documents\coffeeShop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    String coffeeName = NameTXT.Text;
    String coffeeGrid = GrindTXT.Text;
    String coffeeOrigin = OriginTXT.Text;
    String coffeePrice = PriceTXT.Text;
    String coffeeQty = QuantityTXT.Text;
    String coffeeRRP = RRPTXT.Text;

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (coffeeName, coffeeGrid, coffeeOrigin, coffeePrice, coffeeQty, coffeeRRP) VALUES ('%" + coffeeName + "%','%" + coffeeGrid + "%','%" + coffeeOrigin + "%','%" + coffeePrice + "%','%" + coffeeGrid + "%','%" + coffeeQty + "%','%" + coffeeRRP + "%' ", conn);

    conn.Open();
    //SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    //lblDBData.Text += "<table border=0>";
    //while (reader.Read())
    //{
    //    lblDBData.Text += "<tr>";
    //    lblDBData.Text += "<td>" + reader["coffeeName"] + "</td>";
    //    lblDBData.Text += "</tr>";
    //}
    //lblDBData.Text += "</table>";

    //reader.Close();
    conn.Close();                     
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, Many thanks

Comment: Does you have tried executing the code in sql does it works there or throws an error please check it

Comment: You don't execute the command...

Comment: @Soner Gönül why a couple times?

Comment: @SonerGönül some people get it with only one select. (If you catch my drift. ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

`comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

After:

`conn.Open();`

By the way, you would want to use parameters instead of `" + parameter + "`  on query to avoid sql injection. Read this:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: That should be required reading before you're allowed to touch a database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the command as;

```
conn.Open(); //Open the connection to the database
comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //This line does the insert
conn.Close(); //Close the connection once your command executed.
```

Also think about parameterised queries and to open connection object within a `using` block as a good practice to avoid leaving connection objects open.

Ex;

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your query string with @para", conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para", "value");
   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you executes a Transact-SQL statement, the correct way is:

```
    private const string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Matt\Documents\coffeeShop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    protected void SubmitBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Table (coffeeName, coffeeGrid, coffeeOrigin, coffeePrice, coffeeQty, coffeeRRP) VALUES (@name, @grid, @origin, @price, @qty, @rrp)";
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {        

            String coffeeName = NameTXT.Text;
            String coffeeGrid = GrindTXT.Text;
            String coffeeOrigin = OriginTXT.Text;
            String coffeePrice = PriceTXT.Text;
            String coffeeQty = QuantityTXT.Text;
            String coffeeRRP = RRPTXT.Text;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", coffeeName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grid", coffeeGrid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", coffeeOrigin);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", coffeePrice);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", coffeeQty);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rrp", coffeeRRP);

            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException Ex)
            {

                console.WriteLine( "Error message: " + Ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }        

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read an insert statement. You have to use `comm.executeNonQuery()` to execute the insert command, then make a new select statement to read the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the SQL command.  Before closing the connection, add this:

```
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For an example, see MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx